# can not write to hard drive permitions set to root, EMERGENCY!

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, root

I have seen many questions about this but i can not get my drives to be writable. I do not understand the command line. I am on a very tight deadline and wondering if i can pay someone to walk me through this root permissions issue on a EXT2 formatted drive so i can write my files to it.

I am on a MAC and installed Ubuntu in Parallels and los on a laptop on an external drive, i have been working on this for 2 days now and need to deliver this tomorrow nigh Sunday.

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

Okay do this now

```
cd / 
mkdir mnt
```

Mount you drive fast 
then open ternimal and run this

```
sudo chmod -R a+w /mnt/shared
sudo chown -R username /mnt/shared
```

replace the username with your username.

Comment: Thanks but i get a message "No such file or directory"

Comment: The whole message, "chmod: cannot access ‘/mnt/shared’: No such file or directory"